# What is the meaning of "just as it happened"?

Tags: marvel, spider-man-into-the-spider-verse

In *Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse* (2018) (Alt-Universe Cut), Ganke and Miles steal the *Spider-Man* DVD Commentary and watch it.

> Gluck: We did keep Uncle Ben's death **just as it happened**, Spidey. It's
>   the singular motivating incident of your origin story.
>
> Spider-Man: You mean my life.

What is the meaning of "just as it happened"?

Does it mean someone in Spider-Man's life died the same way as
Uncle Ben?

Comment: For any oncoming close votes, we allow "English meaning" questions of they're about a science fiction or fantasy work.

Comment: The English phrase _just as it happened_ means something is being described truthfully, factually, without embellishment, modification, or other editing that could alter the meaning.  It is often reserved for powerful moments whose impact would be lessened by the normal minor editing most parts of a story go through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means they didn't change Ben's death for the movie (as it is an essential part of the Spider-Man origin story).